# PHP not executing in browser, but works when manually executed in CLI

Tags: apache2, php

Im definitely doing something wrong here, but i cant figure out what it is specifically.

my files are located in `/var/www/html/test` just typical php files.

- index.php
- some_function.php

on my index.php, i have an html button, which upon clicking, will be directed to **some_function.php**

```
<a href="some_function.php">EXECUTE</a>
```

supposedly this will output some result.
But upon doing so, the functions inside the page isn't being executed at all.

But, when i manually execute the **some_function.php** script in CLI command

```
[root@webserver test]php some_function.php
```

it works flawlessly.

Comment: This may sound silly, but have you installed `libapache2-mod-php5` ? Verify by `dpkg -l libapache2-mod-php5` or `apt list libapache2-mod-php5`.

Comment: Depends what does `some_function.php` do? Could you add the content of it to your question please? You say it isn't executed .. what happens instead? I guess maybe your script doesn't produce html output and therefore might be executed but you can't see it? If there is some error in apache2 it should appear in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (I think it's called like this)